# How to wait for a async void method to complete its task?

Tags: java, asynchronous, async-await

In Java, we have the Awaitility class, in which we can wait for a boolean returning method to return true or false.

How can we do this for a void method?

Comment: I've never used it, but according to https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility/wiki/Usage, the method you use with `await()` _isn't_ the async method, it's a separate bool-returning function that tells Awaititility _when to finish waiting_.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
await().untilAsserted(() -> someVoidMethod());
```